# org.postgresql.util.PGobject cannot be cast to org.postgis.PGgeometry

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

When I try to load points from a PostGIS database, I get the following
exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.postgresql.util.PGobject
        at org.hibernatespatial.postgis.PGGeometryUserType.convert2JTS(PGGeometryUserType.java:75)
        at org.hibernatespatial.AbstractDBGeometryType.nullSafeGet(AbstractDBGeometryType.java:123)
        at org.hibernatespatial.GeometryUserType.nullSafeGet(GeometryUserType.java:169)
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the problem described in [PGobject cannot be cast to PGgeometry](http://hibernate-spatial.1140993.n2.nabble.com/PGobject-cannot-be-cast-to-PGgeometry-td1141096.html) so I'll quote the relevant answer:

> I guess you run into the same problem as Sebastien Arbogast a while back. If you use Hibernate Spatial in a web container with the JDBC provided by the container through JNDI, then the postgis.jar should also be installed together with the JDBC driver and should *not* be contained in the WEB-INF/lib directory.

Of course, this is a shot in the dark since you didn't mention anything about your environment and didn't provide the full stack trace.

Comment: Good advice! But if you already have geoserver in same server where you want to place your web app, you will face a problem to load geoserver after adding additional postgis.jar. I haven't find solution for this case yet.

Comment: One of solutions is to remove postgresql jar from geoserver lib path so geoserver will be using e.g. tomcat's libs.