# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.postgresql.util.PGobject

Tags: android, postgresql-9.1

Code first:

```
PGpoint coordinates = (PGpoint) rs.getObject(4);
```

Causes ClassCastException.

Referencing postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc3.jar on the project.

Returning a recordset on a android application. Any way to circumvent this?

TIA

Comment: Basically: `rs.getObject(4);` is a `PGObject`, not a `PGPoint`.

Comment: Thx for the input assylias.

Could you be so kind as to elaborate? Because for me PGPoint is a descendant of PGObject ... :)

Comment: If you want us to eleborate, you should provide us with more information. Does it happen sometimes? With all PGxxx objects? Why do you _expect_ it to be a PGpoint? etc.

Comment: @user1214454 let's imagine that your PGObject is a PGbox, it is not a PGPoint and the line you show would throw that kind of Exception.

Comment: you can create a custom type in order to support it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53548731/how-to-work-with-pgpoint-for-geolocation-using-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

This looks very similar to the question [org.postgresql.util.PGobject cannot be cast to org.postgis.PGgeometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698622/org-postgresql-util-pgobject-cannot-be-cast-to-org-postgis-pggeometry). The answer provided there, quoted below, mentions postgis.jar being not installed property. Might this apply to your situation as well? How *did* you install postgis?

> If you use Hibernate Spatial in a web container with the JDBC provided
>   by the container through JNDI, then the postgis.jar should also be
>   installed together with the JDBC driver and should not be contained in
>   the WEB-INF/lib directory

Comment: Hi Paul-Jan.
No, I don't use Hibernate.
As to clarify my question, I do expect it to be a POINT since it's enforced at table-level.
    CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_geometry CHECK (ndims(geometry) = 2)
    
So, in a nutshell, it's a postgis-enabled database. Must I add postgis.jar to the external libraries in my project? If so, what's the correct way of accessing geometry of the type POINT via a resultset?
TIA.